# "trigger option 'interval' must be in the XML duration format

Tags: ansible, scheduled-tasks

I am currently new to Ansible and am trying to set scheduled tasks for specific times. According to the ansible doc, intervals must be in ISO 8601 Duration format which I did but I keep getting this error

> trigger option 'interval' must be in the XML duration format but was
> '19700101T110000-0600, 19700101T050000-0600, 19700101T170000-0600'"}

Code :

```
- name: Setup scheduled task
  community.windows.win_scheduled_task:
    name: Test task
    actions:
    - path: D:\Tasks\testtask.exe
      arguments: '/L'
    path: \testcomp
    triggers:
      - type: daily
        repetition:
          interval: 19700101T110000-0600, 19700101T050000-0600, 19700101T170000-0600
    username: testuser
    state: present
    enabled: '{{ enable_test_tasks }}'
```

Comment: Does the very explicit error message, when combined with [the examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/community/windows/win_scheduled_task_module.html#examples), not help you know what [the ISO duration format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) looks like? I also have better than average confidence it is _singular_, not a CSV of them

Comment: The [`repetition.interval` definition in the same documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/community/windows/win_scheduled_task_module.html#parameter-triggers/repetition/interval) is yet an other hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what the colleagues mean to say is that in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/community/windows/win_scheduled_task_module.html#parameter-triggers/repetition/interval) and specifically in the [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/community/windows/win_scheduled_task_module.html#examples)

where you can find a code like this:

```yaml
- name: Create a task that will be repeated every minute for five minutes
  community.windows.win_scheduled_task:
    name: RepeatedTask
    description: open command prompt
    actions:
    - path: cmd.exe
      arguments: /c hostname
    triggers:
    - type: registration
      repetition:
        interval: PT1M
        duration: PT5M
        stop_at_duration_end: yes
```

Should give enough insight in what it's needed to be mended.

Explanation on what that "interval" and "duration" means [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)

For the example above:

- P is the duration designator (for period) placed at the start of the duration representation.
- Y is the year designator that follows the value for the number of calendar years.
- M is the month designator that follows the value for the number of calendar months.
- W is the week designator that follows the value for the number of weeks.
- D is the day designator that follows the value for the number of calendar days.
- T is the time designator that precedes the time components of the representation.
- H is the hour designator that follows the value for the number of hours.
- M is the minute designator that follows the value for the number of minutes.
- S is the second designator that follows the value for the number of seconds.